# where can I download StoreKit.framework

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

I am trying to implement ios phonegap In app purchasement plugin.

I need to add storekit.Framework to xcode project but cant find one.

I googled storekit.Framework but all information I found was how to use it and what storekit about

but not where is it. can anyone tell me where should I visit to download storekitFramework?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a standard framework available in iOS. To use it, simply

- Select your project
- Select your target
- Select Build Phases
- In Link Binaries with Libraries, click +
- Search for StoreKit and Add

Import the framework in your class.

[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot2]

Answer (score 2):

StoreKit.Framework is already included in all iOS SDK's above 3.0, so there's no need to download it.

To add it to your project, just click your Project's Name on the left-hand panel of Xcode (near the top), and then your project's name again, under the "Targets" section of the now second-to-left hand panel. Now click "Build Phases" near the top of the window, and then expand "Link Binary With Libraries".

Now just hit the "+" at the bottom-left corner, find StoreKit.Framework, and click add. That should do it!